# Julia: Vscode extension to send code to the top?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I often find myself adding a new package midway through the code so I need to add `using Pkg1` or `import Pkg1`. But then this code should sit up the top, so I end up scrolling up to the top, type the using code, and then lose track of where I was in the code.

In some python extension, the import statement can be sent to the top for the user.

Is there a vscode extension to do that for julia code?

Comment: This seems like it could be a job for our auto-formatter. Feel free to open a feature request!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ctrl+g` to travel through lines in VScode.

```
ctrl+g line 1
ctrl+g line x /*replace x with the line you were*/
```

Comment: And if you don't want to remember what line you were at, replace the second part with `Ctrl+Alt+-`, which takes you to the previous cursor position.

Comment: No. The command is called `Go Back`, so just search for that and figure out the shortcut on your system (e.g. on a Mac it might be `Cmd+Meta+-` or something like that). Might even depend on the keyboard layout.